# Label color not changing with tablelayout panel

Tags: c#, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel where a lot of information is being held as label text pairs.  Meaning the first column is labels, the second text boxes, third labels and so on.  I want to colorize the column pairs to make the data more readable.

If the data is a single column pair, I can doc the TableLayoutPanel in a normal Panel, change its color and I'm good to go.  But in this case, I want to closely associate data across 3 column pairs so that it all scrolls together.

To color the table by column, I'm using the CellPaint event, code below.

```
private void tlpEngParts_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
        switch(e.Column)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, r);
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, r);
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, r);
                break;
        }
    }
```

But this leaves the labels all with the default gray forecolor.  How can I have the labels' color match the column color?  Like if there was a Panel with a set color behind it.

Comment: By default a Label's BackColor is transparent. Did you change that?

Comment: No. I just drag the label onto the form.  The color behind the label changes on compile, via the provided code, but does not transfer to the label.